# How to get return javascript value of a global function variable in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, variables, global

Am writing javascript variables that can be assessed from other javascrpt files loaded in a browser window.

my script is as follows

```
window.mysiteVars = {};
window.mysiteVars.myDir = function(){
    if(document.location.href.indexOf('localhost') > -1){
        // i am on localhost
        return 'http://localhost/mysite/';
    }else if(document.location.href.indexOf('mydomain.com') > -1){
        // i am on my remote host
        return document.location.origin+'/';
    }else{
        // i am accessing localhost from another computher in the network
        return document.location.origin+'/mysite/'; 
    }
}
window.mysiteVars.dir1 = window.mysiteVars.myDir()+'dir1/';
window.mysiteVars.dir2 = window.mysiteVars.myDir()+'dir2/';
```

if i do console.log(window.mysiteVars.dir1) or even console.log(mysiteVars.dir1) in any of the javascript files loaded in the page it will returns as expected in chrome, firefox and safari, but in internet explorer it outputs "undefineddir2/
i.e. it returns undefined for the first property of mysiteVars which is a function.

please how do i fix this problem?
thanks.

Comment: use `window.location` not `document.location`

Comment: thanks, but it give the same issue

Comment: I tested it on IE 11

Comment: Code works fine for me on IE11...

Comment: I'm not sure when `origin` property has been added to IE's location object, it's not mentioned in [IE documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Browser_compatibility) seems not to know. Anyway, are you sure you're running the page in standards mode, i.e. you've proper HTML5 doctype?

Comment: Yes sir doctype is correctly declared

Comment: but which other multi-browser compatible function can i use to get same value as window.location.origin ?